# Yarn required before a build in zero-install

Tags: yarnpkg

Following the instructions for [zero installs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs).

I find that a new clone will fail with `yarn run build` with many errors relating to core-js:

```
ERROR in ../../.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-corejs2-npm-7.16.3-f613edc90e-812ff8f560.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/weak-map.js 1:0-55
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/library/fn/weak-map'
```

I don't have deps on @babel, or core-js, so it seems these are core webpack or yarn deps.

However if I run `yarn` first, the build will succeed.  The only diff in this process is `.yarn/install-state.gz`.

While not an awful workaround, is there anything I can do to ensure this is zero config?